# How can I paste the output to the previous output next side?

Tags: python, while-loop

I want result looking like this using "while" function twice.

```
2 5
4 4
8 3
16 2
32 1
```

[the code can also be seen in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/97TT2.png)

so far, I've just done this:

```
i = 2
while i <33:
    print(i)
    i = i *2

j = 5
while j>0:
     print(j)
     j = j-1
```

How can I paste the output alongside?

Comment: edit your code ?

Comment: Is using a while loop twice a requirement? e.g. `print('\n'.join(f'{2 ** i} {6 - i}' for i in range(1,6)))`

Comment: @PeteKirkham very good idea

Answer (score 1):

To achieve the desired result where the output of the two `while` loops is printed alongside, you can use a loop that iterates over the values of `i` and `j` and prints them together.

Here's update code:

```py
i = 2
j = 5

while i >= 1 and j >= 1:
    print(i, j)
    i *= 2
    j -= 1
```

outputs :

```py
2 5
4 4
8 3
16 2
32 1
```